# How is the (None,None,1) input working in keras?

Tags: python, image, input, keras

I am working on a project using a keras deep learning model that i need to transfer into PyTorch . 
The goal of the project is to localize some elements on the images. To train it, I first use patches extracted from my images and then infer on the full image. I read that it was possible with the (None,None,1) input shape for the keras input layer and it is currently working. However, the same training system does not seem to work in pytorch. Therefore i was wondering is the (None,None,1) input layer doing something specific when I start inferring on full images?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

As in the discussion in the [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2054) and referencing the words of `fchollet`:

> *Of course,
>   it's not always possible to have such free dimensions (for instance it's
>   not possible to have variable-length sequences with TensorFlow, but it is
>   with Theano).*

One can assume that it's because the architecture of the framework. As you stated, it may be accepted in **keras**, but not accepted in **PyTorch**.

Comment: Ok but how is it doing that ? is it dividing bigger images in smaller patches ?